# I have an NSmutable array which is bound to arraycontroller and a table view . The array contents are strings and I m able to display them in

Tags: objective-c, binding, nsarraycontroller

I have an NSMutableArray and a table view which displays the data in NSMutable array. The array contents are string and its being displayed properly .

I have used binding to display the data using array controller.

When I try to edit the row of the table view, I get an exception saying error while editing for key path "fsfsfsfs".

Can I know what is the mistake here?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Show us das codz!!! :)

Comment: I haven written any code as it is binding. I have bound table view column to ARRAY controller with arrangedobjects as controllerkey.
I have also bound arraycontroller to appdelegate with modelkeypath as arraycontents

Comment: Your english is quite difficult to understand so without code it will be very difficult for me to help you find your problem.

Comment: There is no code apart from initializing the arrayContents variable. This application uses binding concept which is done xib file. Hope this is understandable?

This is all I have.
-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil!= self)
    {
        _arrayContents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [_arrayContents addObjects:@"sdfsdf"];
         [_arrayContents addObjects:@"sdsdsdsdf"];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: ok, can you give the **exact error** message

Comment: 2013-06-25 13:03:11.038 sample[9535:303] Exception detected while handling key input.
2013-06-25 13:03:11.046 sample[9535:303] Error setting value for key path  of object asdasdasdsasdc (from bound object <NSTableColumn: 0x10011e050> identifier: (null)): [<__NSCFConstantString 0x100002a18> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .